# Android: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord when SAMPLERATE set to 44100

Tags: java, android, sampling, audiorecord

I get an error, when I set the sampling rate to 44100 for the AudioRecord object. When it's 22050 it works fine.

02-16 10:45:45.099  24021-24021/com.vlad.jackcomms E/AudioRecord﹕ frameCount 1024 < minFrameCount 1792

02-16 10:45:45.099  24021-24021/com.vlad.jackcomms E/AudioRecord-JNI﹕ Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.

02-16 10:45:45.099  24021-24021/com.vlad.jackcomms E/android.media.AudioRecord﹕ Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.

02-16 10:45:45.109  24021-24021/com.vlad.jackcomms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL

EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vlad.jackcomms, PID: 24021
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.

Here's the relevant code:

```
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 22050*2;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);

    recorder.startRecording();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't forget to ask for AUDIO_RECORD permission too

```
private void checkRecordPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                123);
    }
```

Comment: This call requires using minimum API level 23

Answer (score 13):

You could check if 44100 is supported by your device.
Android does not provide an explicit method to check it but there is a work-around with AudioRecord class' getMinBufferSize function.

```
public void getValidSampleRates() {
    for (int rate : new int[] {44100, 22050, 11025, 16000, 8000}) {  // add the rates you wish to check against
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        if (bufferSize > 0) {
            // buffer size is valid, Sample rate supported

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3333414 Is your device support 44100 sample rate ?

Comment: Surprisingly, it does not, even though it's a late 2014 phone. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest switching the array order to: `{44100, 22050, 11025, 16000, 8000}`, so that you always try higher recording rates first. This way you can guarantee the highest quality audio recording if the device supports multiple formats.

Comment: They are all supported now :P